# Dynamically change the key in a filter query

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple filtering code that filters out 0s and nulls. Perhaps not the most elegant, but it works:

```js
var data = [{"location": 30, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 60, "year" : 1928},
            {"location": 0, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 50, "year": 0}];
    
var filteredData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  if (data[i].location !== null && data[i].location != 0) {
    filteredData.push({
      location: data[i].location,
      year: data[i].year
    })
  }
};
console.log(filteredData);
```

Now I would like to filter out 0s and nulls for other keys (e.g. year), how can I dynamically change key?

My (perhaps naive) thinking was to create a variable indicating the key I want to filter out

Unfortunately that didn't work.
Does anyone have a suggestion or help me in the right direction?

```js
var var1 = 'year';
    
var data = [{"location": 30, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 60, "year" : 1928},
            {"location": 0, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 50, "year": 0}];

var filteredData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  if (data[i].var1 !== null && data[i].var1 != 0) {
    filteredData.push({
      location: data[i].location,
      year: data[i].year
    })
  }
};

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `data[i].var1` try `data[i][var1]`. the square brackets allows you to have a dynamic key.

Comment: thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. So simple :)

Comment: [That was an easily found dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation for variable keys.

That said, JavaScript has an [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

You can then use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to have dynamic keys in an array:

```js
const data = [{"location": 30, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 60, "year" : 1928},
            {"location": 0, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 50, "year": 0}];

const notZero = ["location","year"]

const filteredData = data.filter(item => notZero.every(key => item[key] !== 0))

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: just my 0.02: use `!==` instead of `!=`

Comment: Yes, bad habit....

Comment: thanks, that is a more elegant solution and will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have 0 or null in your data, you need to do this:

```js
const data = [{"location": 30, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 60, "year" : 1928},
            {"location": 0, "year": 2019},
            {"location": 50, "year": 0}];

const filteredData = data.filter(item => !Object.values(item).filter(value => !value).length)
```

This lets you dynamically check all values within an object and check if all of them are truthy values, thereby catching all falsy values.